# Force CompareString to compare accented characters in the first pass?

Tags: winapi, internationalization, locale

For some languages **[CompareString(Ex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** first compares the characters by ignoring any accents. They are compared in a second pass if the strings are considered equal.

This leads to these sort orders with German umlauts:

```
1. u
2. ü
First pass:  u == u 
Second pass: u <  ü
------
1. üa
2. uz
First pass:  u == u, but a < z
Second pass: Skipped
```

In my use case this is not desired and I wonder if it is possible to somehow force **CompareString** to compare accented characters in the first pass, so that this sort order is achived:

```
1. uz
2. üa
```

The available flags seem to be able to skip the second pass entirely but that would only worsen the problem. I hope there's something I missed. Perhaps (mis-)using one of the sort orders to be used with **MAKELCID**.

Comment: Pretty unclear *exactly* what you are looking for.  CompareStringOrdinal() gives you that sort order.